# Calendar application with Google sync?

Tags: software-recommendation, 13.04

Quick question, I'm looking for Calendar software for Ubuntu 13.04 with Google sync option, is the any available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Thunderbird with Lightning plugin (should work with CalDAV)
- KOrganizer (more at home withing KDE than in Unity, though)
- Evolution should have Google support, or CalDAV.

Answer (score 4):

You can try also this calendar-indicator, really good in my opinion:

http://www.atareao.es/ubuntu/calendar-indicator-0-1-0-0-o-simplemente-espectacular/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install calendar-indicator
```